# Failed to communicate with Peer <xyz> when load balancing data for Connection with ID <abc> due to java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timed out waiting

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a 6 node cluster and most of time in the bulletin I see this message

```
Failed to communicate with Peer nifi-4.nifi-hs:8443 when load balancing data for Connection with ID 4fc4e9f5-017b-1000-0000-00005d8f751e due to java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Peer nifi-4.nifi-hs:8443 to acknowledge Protocol Version
```

Relevant properties are here:

```
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.connect.timeout=30 secs
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.read.timeout=30 secs
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=30 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=30 sec
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=30 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=30 secs
```

This causes some of the nodes in the cluster to become disconnected.
What am I missing  here?

I am on NiFi 1.15.2 using JDK 11.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using Apache NiFi version 1.11.0. I have the similar issue but when I tried on version 1.11.0, everything is working as expected. Hence I believe it could be some security setting is incorrect in our setup.

Comment: I don't want to rollback to older version. I am using 1.15 features. It is most likely not related to security but more with various network timeout settings.